# Questions about fps for airsoft

Tags: airsoft

I’m considering getting the matrix sr25 full metal that shoots 400-450 fps, what is a good minimum engagement distance for this? Me and my friend are playing together so we don’t have a set of rules to go by.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on who you ask, but you're looking at a consensus minimum engagement distance (MED) of around 15 metres and recommended engagement distance (RED) of around 20 metres, and in semi-auto mode only.

A variety of [posts in this forum's thread](https://www.airsoftsniperforum.com/32-general-sniper-talk/10092-fps-rules-around-world-2.html#/topics/10092?page=2), using 0.20g BB ammunition at 450fps, mention variously

- 50 feet (15 metres) (Utah)
- 20 metres (Brazil)
- 10 metres (Indonesia)
- 40 feet (12 metres) (Texas)
- 20 metres (Norway)

Websites for airsoft associations in other countries describe similar limits, MED 15-20 metres and RED 20-25 metres. You may be best advised to start at the high end of the range and work down as you develop comfort with being hit and judgement of appropriately safe distances.